# Can I browse and search man pages in Yelp?

Tags: search, manpage, yelp

I can open Yelp to a specific man page as follows:

```
yelp man:bash &
```

But how can I use Yelp to browse (view a list of all man pages and open them one by one) and search (find all man pages that contain a given string)?

Answer (score 5):

The search feature in yelp is broken and does not include man pages in the results. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505641

This is unsatisfying, but You can press `[Ctrl]+[L]` and enter the man page to display, e.g. `man:bash`.